# Poincaré dual of the Alexander dual of the fundamental class of a knot is given by a Seifert surface

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, cohomology, knot-theory

Let $K\subset S^3$ be an oriented knot and let $F:\overline{B^2}\times K\rightarrow S^3$ be a thickening with self linking number $0$. I will denote $F(B^2\times K)$ by $(B^2\times K)$ for simplicity. Write $X_K:=S^3\setminus(B^2\times K)$ for the knot complement and denote by $i:\partial X_K\rightarrow X$ the canonical inclusion. Denote by $[\mu_K^\star]\in H^1(S^3\setminus(B^2\times K)$ the unique generator with the property that $\langle[\mu_K^\star],\mu_K\rangle =1$ for $\mu_K$ a meridian of $K$. In other words $[\mu_K^\star]$ is the Alexander dual of the fundamental class of $K$. Further let $F_K$ be a Seifert surface for $K$.
I want to show that
$$\left[ \mu_K^\star\right] \frown \left[ S^3\setminus(B^2\times K)\right] = i^J_\star(\left[ F_K'\right]),$$
where $F^\prime_K:=X_K\cap F_K$. To do so I already have proven that the boundary map
$$\partial_2:H_2(S^3\setminus(B^2\times K),S^1\times J;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H_1(S^1\times K;\mathbb{Z})$$
is a monomorphism thus it suffices to show that
$$\partial_2 (\left[ \mu_K^\star\right] \frown \left[ S^3\setminus(B^2\times K)\right] )=\partial_2 (\left[ F_K'\right] ).$$
In particular it suffices to show that
$$\partial([\mu_K^\star]\frown[S^3\setminus (B^2\times K)]) = [\lambda_K],$$
where $\lambda_K$ denotes a longitude for $K$.
I started with using the almost naturality of the Poincaré Duality with respect to the long exact sequence of a pair, this is that the square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
H^k(S^3\setminus(B^2\times K);\mathbb{Z}) @>i^\star>> H^{k}(S^1\times K;\mathbb{Z})\\
@VV\frown[S^3\setminus(B^2\times K]V @V \frown[S^1\times K]VV\\
H_{n-k}(S^3\setminus(B^2\times K),S^1\times K;\mathbb{Z} @>\partial_{n-k}>> H_{n-k-1}(S^1\times K;\mathbb{Z})\\
\end{CD}
commutes up to $(-1)^k$.
Thus one could start calculating
$$\partial_2(\left[ \mu_K^\star\right] \frown\left[ S^3\setminus F(B^2\times K)\right] )        \overset{\text{above}}{=}       -i^\star(\left[ \mu_K^\star\right] )\frown\left[ \partial(S^3\setminus F(B^2\times K))\right]=\color{red}{???}=[\lambda_K]$$
It smells to me like we need to use the
property
$$\varphi\frown f_\star(\sigma)=f_\star(f^\star(\varphi)\frown\sigma)$$ with respect to our thickening. I.p. as Kyle Miller pointed out to me in another question we can rewrite the above to
$$\partial_2(\left[ \mu_K^\star\right] \frown\left[ S^3\setminus F(B^2\times K)\right] )        \overset{\text{above}}{=}       -i^\star(\left[ \mu_K^\star\right] )\frown\left[ \partial(S^3\setminus F(B^2\times K))\right]=$$
$$=-i^\star(\left[ \mu_K^\star\right] )\frown(-F_\star[S^1\times K])=\color{red}{???}=[\lambda_K]$$
This looks very fruitful to me (at least regarding our minus signs).
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not apply Poincare duality one more time, then you are asking about the relation between the Alexander dual to the knot's fundamental class and the Seifert surface.  i.e. you are asking if one computes the linking number with the knot by the signed intersection number with the Seifert surface. This is in many introductory knot theory texts.

Comment: Actually my confusion came from such a proof, which I thought to be wrong and thus I wanted to proof it rigurously, but there was just some confusion in the notation. You can proof that the Poincare dual of the Alexander dual of the fundamental class of a knot is given by a Seifert surface in the above way. All that is missing is an explicit calculation of the cap product on the torus and using the $\varphi\frown f_\star(\sigma)=f_\star(f^\star(\varphi)\frown\sigma)$ trick applied to the thickening. I will post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: It feels like I am still at a very introductory level in knot theory, so sorry if my question came across confusing

Comment: That the cup product translates to intersection product after Poincare/Alexander duality, perhaps the most natural context to prove this in is via triangulations (and the dual CW-decomposition).  You can prove it for singular homology as well.  When the classes are realized by fundamental classes of manifolds, there is a nice proof in Bredon's "Geometry and Topology" algebraic topology text.   But if you see it in the case of triangulated manifolds first, that will probably give you the most concrete idea for how basic these arguments are.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just to finish off the above argument:
Consider the following diagram:
[image]
Then we can continue in our above calculation
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\partial_2(\left[ \mu_K^\star\right] \frown\left[ S^3\setminus F(B^2\times K)\right] )  &   =   &   -i^\star(\left[ \mu_K^\star\right] )\frown F_\star(-\left[ S^1\times K\right] )\\
                &   =   &   -F_\star(F^\star(i^\star(\left[ \mu_K^\star\right] ))\frown(-\left[ S^1\times K\right]) )\\
                &   =   &   -F_\star(\left[ S^1\times\left\lbrace \star\right\rbrace \right] ^\star\frown(-\left[ S^1\times K\right] ))\\
                &   =   & -(F_\star(-\left[ \left\lbrace \star\right\rbrace \times K\right] ))\\
                &   =   &   \left[ \lambda_K\right] = \left[ \partial F^\prime_K\right] = \partial\left[ F^\prime_K\right] .
\end{array}$$
where in the second to last row we used the explicit calcualtion of the cap product on a torus, this is:
Let $T=S^1\times S^1$ be the torus. Then the isomorphism
$$\frown\left[T\right]:H^1(T;\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H_1(T;\mathbb{Z})$$
given by capping with the fundamental class satisfies
$$\left[\left\lbrace \star\right\rbrace \times S^1\right]^\star\mapsto-\left[S^1\times\left\lbrace\star\right\rbrace\right]$$
and
$$\left[S^1\times\left\lbrace\star\right\rbrace\right]^\star\mapsto\left[\left\lbrace\star\right\rbrace\times S^1\right].$$

Comment: Lovely, thanks!